# Is this function overloading correct?

Tags: c++, overloading

Consider having these four functions in one C++ program:

```
void a(int val)
{
    cout<<val;
}
void a(int &val)
{
    cout<<val;
}
void a(int *val)
{
    cout<<val;
}
void a(double val)
{
    cout<<val;
}
```

Few Questions i have are:

Is there going to be any error in the code? or are they all overloaded without any error.
Can you tell me how to call all of these four functions correctly? My try was below:

```
int iTmp; 
int *pTmp; 
double dTmp;

a(iTmp); 
a(iTmp); 
a(pTmp); 
a(dTmp);
```

Comment: The implementation seems correct to me. Is there some actual problem?

Comment: @Codor I'm not sure either.. It's an interview question

Comment: `a(iTmp);` is amgiguous.

Comment: What would be the error? That calls to `void a(int val)` would be impossible to distinguish from calls to `void a(int &val)`?

Comment: The first and second functions are ambiguous - they are called in exactly the same manner so it isn't possible to determine which one you want.

Comment: Did you mean `const int &val`?

Comment: @MohitJain ...not that it would matter.

Comment: @Kvothe: Be aware that this only applies from the developper's view - from binary code view, a(int&) and a(int*) will be far closer one to another than a(int)...

Comment: @AbdulJabbar out of curiosity did you consider your calling `a(iTmp)` *twice*? It isn't like one will choose one overload, while the other chooses... the other. *Both* of them are ambiguous, and only one call would be required to show that. Odd interview question indeed.

Comment: @WhozCraig well yes, i wrote that then explained that this will be ambiguous but wasn't sure if compiler will throw some error or do its own random calling thing

Comment: @AbdulJabbar just for kicks, take both calls away, and try `a([&](){return iTmp;}());` instead.

Comment: @WhozCraig lol, that might be a bit too over my head

Comment: Its just a lambda that returns an `int`, not a lvalue-reference to `int`, so the first function will be called. Doing something similar for the second would be considerably more twisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem are the functions:

```
void a(int &val)
```

and

```
void a(int val)
```

The compiler will create the following errors:

```
Compilation error   time: 0 memory: 3140 signal:0
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:28:8: error: call of overloaded 'a(int&)' is ambiguous
  a(iTmp); 
        ^
```

Because he cant distinguish both, if you remove one of them the compilation succeeds

See Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void a(int val)
{
    cout<<val;
}
void a(int *val)
{
    cout<<val;
}
void a(double val)
{
    cout<<val;
}

int main() {
    int iTmp = 0; 
    int *pTmp = 0; 
    double dTmp = 0.0;

    a(iTmp); 
    a(iTmp); 
    a(pTmp); 
    a(dTmp);
    return 0;
}
```

See working example:

http://ideone.com/WRZUoW

Comment: The variables are not initialized, they could or could not have a value of 0 (zero/null pointer), the output is not guaranteed (by the standard) to be what is depicted in the example!

Comment: your are right i adopted the example from the asker - now i initialized them sorry for that

Comment: *Because he [the compiler] cant distinguish both*. ....umm.. that is not correct to say. The compiler can definitely distinguish them, just that it is not allowed (by the language) to consider one of them as better match than the other, which is why it says there is ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will compile but calling

```
int iTmp; 
a(iTmp);
```

will yield an ambiguous overload resolution call since both

```
void a(int val)
{
    cout<<val;
}
void a(int &val)
{
    cout<<val;
}
```

will match.

The reason for this lies in the standard:

[over.match.best]

> A viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2)

```
int->int
int->int&
```

these are standard conversion sequences and the entire list of `[over.ics.rank]p3.2` is checked without success for a better conversion sequence (**exact match** in both cases)

They are thus deemed "undistinguishable".

A word of advice: the variable are also not initialized and (if automatic variables) even if your code compiled, the output would be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler must be able to know what function to call.

With

```
int i = 12;
a(i);
```

both `a(int i)` and `c(int& i)` are acceptable candidates and compiler throws an error.

and

```
void a(const int& i) { ... }
```

will suffer from same problem.

Answer (score 0):

These two function will cause issues

```
void a(int val)
{
    cout<<val;
}
void a(int &val)
{
    cout<<val;
}
```

Your call `a(iTmp);` have two possible candidates. Compiler should shown an error for these. Otherwise pointer argument(`int *val`)and double argument(`double val`) are okay.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem is that

```
  void a(int val) {
```

and

```
void a(int& val) {
```

are ambiguous when called with `iTmp`.

Aside from that, depending on whether the variables are global or local ones, the code is using uninitialized variables -> UB and whether or not,

```
void a(int* val) {
   std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

is overloaded correctly is up for debate. I'd assume that it should be `std::cout << *val << std::endl;`, but that of course depends on what the function is supposed to do (although a function that prints an address would usually be parameterized by (void* or char*);